# how to convert a visible image into infrared image with matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need some infrared image to do some experiment ,but I just have some color images...
while,is it possible to convert a color image into a infrared image?

just need for simulation...

Comment: I assume you have left out some crucial context here, or else you have a very deep misunderstanding of the words "color" and "infrared"

Answer (score 5):

By definition a visible color image shows only visible light. The camera does not (or is prevented from) capturing IR wavelengths.
Thus, what you are asking is not really possible if/when the IR wavelength are not captured.